# Read saved steam password

Tags: steam

Is there any way to "read" a saved steam password?

I have my password set in steam for ages and recently I wanted to log into my account from my mobile device, but I just cant remember my password so far.

In addition I want to upgrade to Windows 10 the next days but before I do that I need to know my steam password.

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 11):

**No.**

Only an extremely poorly-written program will provide a way to view its own stored password<sup>1</sup>, as this is a major security risk. If you could view your saved password, then it could also be accessed by a remote user over the network.

Since your password is currently saved in Steam, the best course of action is to first verify that the email address associated with your Steam account is one to which you have access, then do a password reset, and remember what you change it to.

---

<sup>1</sup> While it is true that browsers allow you to view the passwords you've saved for *websites,* they do not allow you to view the password used to log into the browsers *themselves.* This is what I mean by "**its own** stored password".

Comment: All of the modern browsers allow to view saved passwords, it IS a viable strategy not only in the domain of extremely poorly-written programs.

Comment: @Deltharis true, except that the passwords shown this way are not those of the system showing them. Chrome will not display the password used to login to Chrome itself, for example.

Comment: I edited my answer to specify the program not displaying **its own** password.

Comment: @DanHenderson, **How is this possible?** Surely if the information is stored on the user's computer, it must be retrievable somehow?

Comment: @Pacerier any program with login functionality should be encrypting the password locally before transmission (so that the password can't be captured by a MITM attack). The program would therefore store the already-encrypted password, not the password itself.

Comment: The above comment is wrong. You do not transmit encrypted credentials, you transmit credentials over an encrypted channel (TLS) to prevent MITM attacks. If you encrypt and send (or more likely hash and send), the attacker can just re-send the encrypted password, thus negating the use of encryption. See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4936

Comment: @Nemo Thanks, you are correct I see. Upon further research: Any program that allows you to save your password should be encrypting it before **storing** it locally. The program would then need to decrypt the stored password before sending it over an encrypted *channel* (encrypted using a different method) for authentication with a remote server. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) describes one way to encrypt locally-saved passwords - using the user's Windows login credentials - but there are plenty of other ways it could be done.

Comment: Correct. However, this encryption can be defeated by an attacker to retrieve the actual password, since it is entirely client side. I spent some time figuring out if Steam does this, and it does not.

It takes the more simpler route of generating a token for your computer when you click Remember Me. You can likely copy across your steam profile entirely and get it working in another computer, but you can't recover your password from that token.

Comment: There is an invention waiting yet to be invented to FUCKING PERMANENTLY SOLVE this PERMANENTLY FUCKING UNSOLVED PROBLEM: keeping track of random but crucial small bits of information whose validity lifecycle is significantly longer than the lifecycle of any given "password manager" application, or a computer it is installed on for that matter. By "solve" I mean come up with something that requires EXACTLY ZERO CHANGE OF CURRENT HABITS from the user. /rant